# Do gca().lines and legend.get_lines() return the lines in the same order?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Do `gca().lines` and `legend.get_lines()` return the lines in the same corresponding order?

If not, is there a way to get corresponding legend lines from `gca().lines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label="test1")
ax.plot([1, 2], [3, 5], label="test2")
ax.plot([6, 7], [8, 9], label="test3")
legend = ax.legend()

for ax_line, legend_line in zip(ax.lines, legend.get_lines()):
    print(ax_line.get_label(), legend_line.get_label())
```

Output:

```
test1 test1
test2 test2
test3 test3
```

Looks like they do. In other words, `ax.lines` and `legend.get_line()` both store the lines in the order they were created.

Edit: See JohanC's disclaimer below my answer. My answer assumes the plots are simple line or scatter plots and the legend is automatically created. And if only some lines have labels, then the line orders will still be the same but `ax.lines` will have more lines than `legend.get_lines()`.

Comment: OP didn't explain how they created the legend. Things get more complicated when some lines don't have a label. Or when more complicated elements are added, e.g. box plots. Seaborn also combines or skips elements. Stacked plots can have the legend in reversed order to match the visual order in the plot. Future matplotlib versions can behave differently. In general, you should try not to rely on a fixed order.

Comment: @JohanC Those are all reasonable concerns. I added a little disclaimer to my answer in response.